# Get every row in a table if (as a group) they satisfy a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `Students (id, fname, lname)` and `Registrar (id, student_id, class_id)`.  I teach a class with class ID 99.  I want to find all students in my class, and list those students *and all the other classes they're taking*.  I can do the following:

```
SELECT s.fname, s.lname, r.class_id FROM
    Students AS s JOIN Registrar AS r ON s.id = r.student_id WHERE
      r.student_id IN
         (SELECT student_id FROM Registrar WHERE class_id = 99);
```

This works, but it's slow.  I don't have a lot of experience with this (and as my title suggests, I have no idea what this is called), but I'm guessing it's a fairly common problem to solve.  Any pointers in the right direction are most welcome.

Comment: I don't see why your query should be slow. Do you have an index on Registrar.Student_ID? How big are the tables? How do you know is slow?

Comment: MySQL is known to optimize `IN (SELECT...)` poorly. If you `EXPLAIN` these queries, you'll see that instead of getting the results from the subquery and looking them up in the main table's index, it does a full scan of the main table and then looks them up in the index of the subquery's table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. Join to the registar table once on the `class_id = 99` condition, and then again with no `class_id` restriction to get ALL the classes for the student.

```
select s.fname, s.lname, r2.class_id
  from students s
    inner join registrar r
      on s.id = r.student_id
        and r.class_id = 99
    inner join registrar r2
      on s.id = r2.student_id;
```

[demo fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37c78/1)

With an index `(student_id, class_id)` on registrar table, and on `id` in student table, this should be quite fast.

**based on comments**
it's possible classes may be repeated - we can just group to get rid of those:

```
select s.fname, s.lname, r2.class_id
  from students s
    inner join registrar r
      on s.id = r.student_id
        and r.class_id = 99
    inner join registrar r2
      on s.id = r2.student_id
  group by s.id, r2.class_id
```

This abuses mysql's handling of group by somewhat, but its okay because `fname` and `lname` are identical in every row within each group

Comment: Thanks, this is very fast (even without indexing).  I will mention that it relies on class_id being unique; for example, if instead I did the first join on `class_name rlike MATH` (so that the same student could be selected multiple times for the first join) then lots of records get repeated.

Comment: @SteveD well that wasn't part of the question, or the table description, so could hardly be accounted for. If you post some updated details, i will update the answer

Comment: Oh no, I wasn't complaining.  I was simply mentioning it (and it is not part of my table).

Comment: well in that case - correct. another instance it could fail is if registrar table was historical, and people repeated classes. in that case, you could probably just force a fix with  `group by s.fname, s.lname, r2.class_id`

Comment: Yes, class IDs are repeated where I am, but luckily I have the table only for the current semester, so I don't have this problem.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Performance issues aside, DISTINCT seems more appropriate in this case

Comment: semantically yes but i've never been sure if distinct will apply to a whole row or just the field its against :)

Answer (score 2):

`IN` statement is usually slow.
Then you can get better performance by using `EXISTS` statement like :

```
SELECT s.fname, 
       s.lname, 
       r.class_id 
FROM   students AS s 
       JOIN registrar AS r 
         ON s.id = r.student_id 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   registrar 
               WHERE  registrar.student_id = s.id 
                      AND registrar.class_id = 99);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I just checked, and this is about the same performance as the original query.  One thing that is probably slowing things down is that class_id is not indexed.

Comment: @SteveD Not indexing `class_id` will slow down any query that tries to do this.

Comment: you can avoid the correlated subquery altogether with an additional join - that may help, or it may be the same. you'll have to test it

Comment: @barmar thanks. in this case, I think that adding index registrar(student_id, class_id) is better. what do you think?

Comment: That should work for this correlated subquery. For the joins, you need an index on `class_id` by itself. A composite index on `(class_id, student_id)` would work for both. The order of columns in a composite index is important for this.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, but the joining key is student_id??

Comment: Yes. You need to look up all the students by `class_id`, then join that with the rest of the query by `student_id`

Comment: `(student_id, class_id)` is the correct order, not `(class_id, student_id)`. the first join is only on `registrar.student_id`,  `class_id` is not used in that join, so the composite index beginning with `class_id` would not be utilised. This can be verified in the fiddle posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also join with multiple items in your clause:

```
SELECT s.fname, s.lname, r.class_id
FROM Registrar r
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT student_id 
        FROM Registrar 
        WHERE class_id = 99) as t
    ON r.student_id = t.student_id
    INNER JOIN Students s
    ON r.student_id = s.id
```

You really want to try to get as much done in your joins as you can.

Comment: I don't think this works: it only returns one record for each student, corresponding to class_id 99.  But if Adam is in my class, and also registered for 3 others, I should see his name 4 times in the result of the query.